# Can you change the name of a C# Winforms button via the App.config file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms app with buttons that when clicked go to various internal and external locations (Network locations/Web paths) I was asked if it was possible for the end users to have their own names for the buttons, instead of what I called them.

I've created an App.config file so if the links change they can at least edit that file reflecting the change in path/URL etc

The button properties text field doesn't appear to allow code behind it.

```
private void GoogleS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string GoogleS = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"];
                Process.Start(GoogleS);
            }
            catch (Exception GoogleErr)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(GoogleErr.Message);
            }
        }
```

And the key inside the App.config file

```
<add key="Google"   value="http://www.google.com/" />
```

And the fix

App.config

```
<add key="GoogleButton"       value="Google Search"/>
<add key="GoogleLink"         value="http://www.google.com"/>

//Code for the Button names which are loaded on Form Loading from the App.config file
        private void CSS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnGoogleS.Text =   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleButton"];
        }

private void btnGoogleS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string GoogleS = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleLink"];
                Process.Start(GoogleS);
            }
            catch (Exception GoogleErr)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(GoogleErr.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnGoogleS_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.btnGoogleS, (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleLink"]));
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually set the button captions:

```
btnGoogle.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleCaption"];
```

Probably you would do it in a Form Load handler.

Comment: Thanks Blorgbeard, that did it!

Comment: @drneel, sorry new to the site I'm still learning, now fixed.